# What happens to accessories equipped to Claves?

Tags: eternal-sonata

Before entering Andante I equipped her with 2 accessories. One gave Regen and the other Light Body; I did so thinking that she would remain in the party as my healer until I got Polka back, but:

> when I saw her die, the accessories weren't in my inventory.

Since I haven't met back up with Retto, I'm wondering if I get those accessories back after meeting back up with him, or if they are now lost forever.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you like to play your games this can be considered very spoilery so read at your own risk.

> It is possible to get Claves back much later in the game.

I believe you will get those accessories back at this point.

Comment: great, i had hoped to give the accessories to Polka once i met back up with Retto, i guess i'll keep playing and see if she still has them

Comment: @Memor-X: Out of curiosity, did you get the accessories back? Lol.

Comment: @Omega not yet, finding the AI for item targeting to be a pain in the ass when trying to balance out bosses that keep one shoting me if i don't do a perfect defence, even when i'm on the required level a walk though tells me to be on and was that a grind